# Structure of conditional function?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple html dom documents, and some elements have the same id on different documents, I want to write just one function to Query any document passed to it, I will explain :

Currently I have this structure :

```
If(document.getElementById('myid1') != null)
// do Something

If(document.getElementById('myid2') != null)
// do Something

If(document.getElementById('myid3') != null)
// do Something

If(document.getElementById('myid4') != null)
// do Something

If(document.getElementById('myid5') != null)
// do Something

If(document.getElementById('myid6') != null)
// do Something
```

Is there a way to structure this better?
If for each page (document) I write a function I'll have like 30 functions doing the same thing, so I thought on writing just one global function. Any advices?

EDIT :

```
If(document.getElementById('name') != null)
document.getElementById('name').value = name;

If(document.getElementById('company') != null)
document.getElementById('company').value = com;

If(document.getElementById('email') != null)
document.getElementById('email').value = email;

If(document.getElementById('mail') != null)
document.getElementById('mail').value = email;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the “do something”s have any common structure?

Comment: No, it fills the attribute 'value'  with a different variable depending on the element.

Comment: Please explain your problem using real examples. In a comment below, you say that the string is each time different. Please show real examples of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you note that all the “do something” bits do is fill a `value` property. I'd say that's a common structure.

In its simplest form, you need to keep a list of pairs of element IDs and values to try to put in those elements. Since the element IDs will be unique, I think a mapping would be appropriate:

```
var values = {
    myid1: "Hello, world! You're looking at the element with the ID of myid1.",
    myid2: "I'm the element with the ID of myid2!"
};
```

Clearly, then, the procedure is to loop through the pairs, looking for the element. If it's there, set the value; otherwise, not a problem: just move on.

In JavaScript, you can loop over the pairs in an object using a `for`..`in` loop. It's a little tricky, though, since you only want to check own properties; that is, properties that belong to that object specifically, and weren't inherited from somewhere else.

Anyway, when put together, you might end up with something like this:

```
for(var id in values) {
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(values, id)) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if(element !== null) {
            element.value = values[id];
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Beyond values

That approach clearly works well for constant values, but you might want to retrieve the values from somewhere else. Can we extend this solution to dynamically-calculated values?

Yes. Rather than storing strings as the values of our mapping, we can store functions. When we want to access the value, we'll just call the function, and the function can do whatever it wants in order to calculate the value. A new mapping might look like this:

```
var values = {
    // If there's something on the page with an ID of nameDisplay, prompt the
    // user for what to fill it with.
    nameDisplay: function() {
        return prompt("What's your name?", "");
    },
    // If there's an element with an ID of time on the page, fill it with the
    // current time.
    time: function() {
        var now = new Date();
        return now.toString();
    }
};
```

Our loop needs little modification. All we need to do is change the line that gives `value` its value  to:

```
element.value = values[id]();
```

Note the parentheses. Now we're calling a function that we stored in the mapping.

Comment: Wow **icktoofay-sensei** thanks a loooot, I knew I'll find a better way to write that function here in stackoverflow. Thanks a lot again :D

Answer (score 3):

You can create one JS file and import one js file in all pages. in that JS page then write in a way which can identify request coming from which page and if that is known you will come to know elements in that page.

Comment: I'm bad at explaining, sorry but I don't technically own the pages to add the JS code, I know I said "I have", I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, thanks a lot for your quick answer. :)

Comment: "I don't technically own the pages" .... you mean to say you can't add new js page?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: if that is the case, I don't see any solution as you have to modify same particular js for each page. for making it generic, you have to add one page which all jsp/html files can refer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I liked **icktoofay**-sama's solution I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 0; i < max_number; ++i)
{

If(document.getElementById('myid'+i) != null)
// do Something
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer, I didn't explain well it is my fault, but the ids are not with numbers, it is a string and each time different :/

Comment: So make an array of strings and iterate over it.